# Spring Security and Angular 7. Login POST request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, frontend, angular7

I want login to my backend app(Spring Boot and Security), but I have problem with login from Angular app. When I do request from Postman everything works. 
I have my own implementation of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` and when I debug this I see that in request from Angular I don't have any params. (I check this in `onAuthenticationFailure` method by calling `System.out.println(request.getParameter("username"));`). 
When I do request from Postman I see login, of course I set incorrect login.

Here is my code from frontend auth service.

```
export class SecurityService {

 private baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient){

 }

login(){
console.log(this.baseUrl);

let username = 'user';
let password = 'userPass';

let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password })
let httpParams = new HttpParams();
httpParams = httpParams.append('username', username).append('password', password);
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });


this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "login", {body, headers})
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));

}

}
```

I don't know how build this request in angular and I still heave 401 status after request. I don't see any help in tutorials from Google or Youtube.

[image]
EDIT: Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private SuccessHandler successHandler;

@Autowired
private FailureLoginHandler failureLoginHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass")).roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("userPass")).roles("USER");

}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/foo").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .failureHandler(failureLoginHandler)
            .and()
            .logout();
}


}
```

Comment: Without seeing your security config, it sounds like you set up all endpoints to require authentication. If the is the case, you need to expose the `/login` endpoint to all traffic.

Comment: well you do not pass params to angular request. why do you expect them to be available on server?

Comment: @TheHeadRush You can see my config, I think that it is ok because it works from postman.

Comment: @NormundsKalnberzins I am not sure how pass login data. As a body, params or what? I do many combinations and now I don't have idea and knowlage how to do in correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late with my answer.

If you can, i suggest to abandon the loginForm path for an Oauth2/Oidc (more secure, can be stateless, cloud oriented) or Basic Authentication (ready to go!). If you choose for Basic Auth, follow the spring official tutorial and everything will go smooth https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

In case you have to mantain LoginForm we found 2 angular way to pass data:

First one **(brutal)**

```
return this.http.post<any>(<my_login_url>, {}, {
    params: new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        username: form.username,
        password: form.passowrd
        submit: 'login'
      }
    })
  })
```

Second one **(clean&smooth)**

```
const loginForm: FormData = new FormData();
loginForm.append('username', form.username);
loginForm.append('password', form.password);
loginForm.append('submit', 'login');
return this.http.post(<my_login_url>, loginForm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this [blog](https://grokonez.com/java-integration/angular-spring-boot-jwt-authentication-example-angular-6-spring-security-mysql-full-stack-part-3-build-frontend), it will perfectly guide you about Authentication with Spring Security and Angular. I have also used this in my project.